# Division using Double.TryParse and if-else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, devexpress, tryparse

I am new to C# programming and I am trying to perform division between two cell values and put the result in a third cell in Devexpress. My code works fine except when the denominator is `0`. This gives me an output of Infinity. Below is my attempt at trying to make it output `0` in the denominator is zero.

```
private void xrTableCell40_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
   string value;
   bool Isnum;
   double holder;
   string zero;
   value = xrTableCell38.ToString();
   zero = 0.ToString(); 
   Isnum = double.TryParse(value, out holder);
   if(Isnum = true){
      if (holder > 0)
         DoWorkEventArgs}
      else{
         xrTableCell40.Text = zero;};
   holder = Convert.ToDouble(xrLabel135.Summary.GetResult()) / Convert.ToDouble(xrTableCell38.Summary.GetResult());
   string s = string.Format("{0:N2}", holder);
   xrTableCell40.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
}
```

I need the output to be `0.00` if the denominator is zero, otherwise it should perform the division and place the result in `xrTableCell40`.

Comment: Does this even compile?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: You have a logic error here: `if(Isnum = true){`... you're setting `Isnum` to `true`. Try updating to `if(Isnum == true){`

Comment: Isnum = true? maybe just Isnum or Isnum == true

Comment: What is DoWorkEventArgs? And what if holder is less than zero?

Comment: I fixed that and now I am getting an error that says 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: What is `xrTableCell38`? Is it a `double`? Why are you converting it to a string, then to a `double`? Why not just convert it directly to a `double`?

Comment: That handler isn't present in the code you provided. And in the code you did provide, the random `DoWorkEventArgs` isn't going to compile.

Comment: If holder is less than 0 it should also output 0.00.

Comment: @Roland....also, there is no case in your if statment if Isnum is true and holder is 0

Comment: xrTableCell38 is a summary function that sums all of the numbers in a certain date range together.

Answer (score 2):

Basic ternary operator usage

```
double value = denom == 0 ? 0 : div/denom;
```

---

to explain the ternary or `?:` operator:

if `cond` is true, than `cond ? a : b` evaluates to a.  otherwise, `cond ? a : b` evaluates to `b`

hopefully you can use this to find yourself a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Isnum = true){ // Isnum = true is assignment, what you need is comparision
    if (holder > 0)
        DoWorkEventArgs}
else{
    xrTableCell40.Text = zero;}; // un-needed ; only statement terminates with semi-colon
```

Should have been

```
        if(Isnum == true) // or (Isnum)
        {
            if (holder > 0)
                DoWorkEventArgs() // missing (), assuming that DoWorkEventArgs is a method call
        }
        else
        {
            xrTableCell40.Text = zero;
        }
```

Comment: I get 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs' is a 'type' but is used lie a 'variable' error

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer:

```
zero = string.Format("{0:N2}", 0);
```

This code certainly isn't going to win you any style points.  A couple of quick hints:

- Use variables that mean something.  I would expect to see "denominator" as a variable somewhere.
- Declare and use variables at the same time - it will improve readability.  Using your code example, go with

  string value = xrTableCell38.ToString();
- Work a little bit on the flow and readability of your code

Good luck, and remember that practice makes perfect.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm still working on this one, but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Roland...., there is no case in your if statment where Isnum is true and holder is 0

Try This:

```
private void xrTableCell40_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        string value;
        bool Isnum;
        double holder;
        string zero;
        value = xrTableCell38.ToString();
        zero = 0.ToString(); 
        Isnum = double.TryParse(value, out holder);
            if(Isnum != true)
            {
              xrTableCell40.Text = zero;
            }
            else if (holder > 0)
            {
              holder = Convert.ToDouble(xrLabel135.Summary.GetResult()) / Convert.ToDouble(xrTableCell38.Summary.GetResult());
              string s = string.Format("{0:N2}", holder);
              xrTableCell40.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
            }
            else
            {
              xrTableCell40.Text = zero;
            } 
  }
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way but I get these errors ; expected  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.DateTime'  Invalid expression term ')' 
 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToDouble(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Roland...it's hard to say without seeing all the code, but I think if you used Convert.ToDouble(xrLabel135.Text) and Convert.ToDouble(xrTableCell38.Text) that would help.  You could also use you value variable as it is already set to xrTableCell38.

Comment: I cannot use Text because it is a summary field that is calculated at run time. I had that error before and it said it was an invalid type

Comment: @Roland...you have some code, value = xrTableCell38.ToString();
, that I assume works.  You could use that in the denominator

Comment: Thank you Mike. Your code helped me reach my goal. I'm sure I could be cleaner and could have approached it better, so please leave me some feedback on my answer posted above.

Comment: @Roland...I think the code in my answer looks good.  Let me know if you need more assistance

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all of your help. This is what I finally came up with and it works.

```
 private void xrTableCell40_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
         {
         string value;
         bool Isnum;
       double holder;
       string zero;
             value = xrTableCell38.ToString();
             zero = 0.ToString();
         Isnum = double.TryParse(value, out holder);
         if (Isnum == true)
         {
             if (holder > 0)
                 holder = Convert.ToDouble(xrLabel135.Summary.GetResult()) / Convert.ToDouble(xrTableCell38.Summary.GetResult());
             else
             {

                 xrTableCell40.Text = Convert.ToString(zero);
                 //xrTableCell40.Text = zero;
             }
             string s = string.Format("{0:N2}", holder);
             xrTableCell40.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
         }


     }
```

Comment: I also just noticed that the xrTableCell40.Text = Convert.ToString(zero); is unnecessary and changed it to xrTableCell40.Text = zero;